# What are these two "clips" on the bolts holding by rear disc brake bracket to the frame?

Tags: frames, disc-brake

My rear disc brake is attached to a bracket, which is attached to the frame.
This bracket is held by two bolts that each have a clip on them:

[image: rear disc brake bracket]

The clips are clamped around the bolts, and can easily be twisted around the bolt (without the bolt moving).

What are they for?

Comment: Modern version of Lawyer Lugs. With the raise of though axles, the lawyers needed something to do.

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29148/how-are-these-plastic-rings-used-on-my-shimano-disk-brake-mount-adapter  but the link to the original question is missing.  Readding in this comment.

Comment: I was confused by this as well, but then figured it might not be showing the link in the comments by design, as it is shown in the "Linked" section in the right sidebar.

Comment: It's definitely supposed to be there, there's a colon missing a list. it's handy that it is in the sidebar too but should be both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.jensonusa.com/Shimano-XT-BR-M775-Caliper-Fixing-Bolt:

> Keeps the bolt from backing out. Torq the bolt then slip the lock over the bolt head and rotate in the direction the bolt would unscrew unntil the tabs hit something. This will stop the bolt from turning if it loosens.

Also: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/29154/908